# how i can make is_english function

Tags: php

I want a php function that check if the input is English and with `dot .` like
`me.too` and no spaces

Comment: I'm not familiar with PHP, but you won't find a built in function for this. You will be able to find an open source English word list though (a quick google will provide some), then check the parts before and after the dot to see if they're valid English words.

Answer (score 4):

Its not very clear what you are asking for, but I *guess* you want to check if a string is made of *only* alphabets and dot. If so you can do:

```
if ( preg_match('/[a-z.]+/i',$input) ) {
  // $input contains only alphabets and period.
}
```

Comment: Don't you need to escape that period, or am I being dumb?

Comment: @Christian: Inside a character class the `.` is treated literally.

Comment: Whereas the `-` is always a meta character, correct?

Comment: It's valid to put redundant escapes on non-letters, this saves remembering of escape rules.

Answer (score 1):

Again. Unclear what you mean. If you want to determine the language of a block of text, then use some heuristics or a regex with the most common words in a language. (Did this once, but too lazy to grab it out.)

If you want to proofcheck if a a given string only contains **correct english** words, then use a spellchecker. Use codaddicts regex to validate the format. Then pipe it through aspell:

```
$words = escapeshellcmd(strtr($words, ".", " "));
$r = `echo '$words' | LANG=en aspell -a`;
$valid = !preg_match("/^[^@*]/m", $r);  // output may not contain ^&
```

Or use the pspell extension / or upgradephp.